# is it possible to install django beta with pip?

Tags: django

I've tried a few variants of

```
pip install django==1.4b1 -E canvas
```

in an attempt to install the beta the easy way.

is there a way to do it?

or do i just have to swallow the pain of downloading and unzipping.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
pip install svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/#egg=django
```

github repository:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/django/django.git@1.5c1
```

Answer (score 3):

[Pip docs](http://guide.python-distribute.org/pip.html#installing-from-a-vcs): Installing from a VCS

```
pip install -e svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/#egg=Django
```

Comment: That -e flag may not be the best option here.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18070479/785400 for more.